# JHipster Spring How can i disable jackson json serialisation ?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jackson, jhipster

i'm developing a rest api webservice with jHipster , i wanna make field filter like facebook graph api (Example: http://myjhipster_web_service.com/api/user?fields=id,username)
the problem is i don't know how to make jackson Json serialization do that, so i decided to make a ResponseBodyAdvice and serialize data by my self, 
and for performance concerns i wanna disable Jackson serialisation so that the response will not be serialized twice.
so my Question is how to disable only jackson response serialisation in Jhipster ? and is there another solution to do the work ?

Answer (score 0):

**First idea**

You can wrap your request (the selected fields) and the result (the user/s) in the REST controller, e.g. in a certain class like `GraphResponse`.

If your mapping in the REST controller returns a `GraphResponse`, Jackson tries to serialize that.

So, you can add your own seriablizer for that class:

```
public class GraphResponseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<GraphResponse> {

@Override
public void serialize(GraphResponse response, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, 
    SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    // use jsonGenerator to write the JSON-stuff
}
```

}

You can either register that serializer via the `JacksonConfiguration` or using an annotation like:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = GraphResponseSerializer.class)
public class GraphResponse {
   // setter getter for "fields"
   // setter getter for the actual response-object
}
```

**Second idea**

You can modify how the beans/entities are serialized by adding your own `BeanSerializerModifier`, which is (AFAIR) responsible for that.

**Third idea**

You can add your own `HttpMessageConverter`, which handles the object to http-output and http-input to object conversion. Since Jackson is executed, because a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is automatically registered, you may alternatively override the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and implement something to turn of the serialization...

**Fourth idea**

In some projects we used GraphQL (http://graphql.org/), where you can use graph queries, which is really powerful and does all the filtering etc. for you based on the entities. There is also a spring-boot-starter for GraphQL, so you can really easy add this to a jhipster project